# Text extends outside button HTML

Tags: html, css

https://plnkr.co/edit/dZigMtncPEed4MK75swb?p=preview

```
<button style="width: 50px" type = "submit">Very very very verey looooooooooooooooooooooong</button>
```

As you can see, the text extends outside. Is there any way to truncate the text? The reason behind this is it is that the button is part of a drop down menu.

[image]

The text is white so it might hard to see it 'breaking' the button.

[UPDATE]

Is there anyway to add margin to the text-overflow: ellipsis. The ellipsis is too close to the text and it is not appealing (in my opinion)

[image]

[UPDATE 2]
Since I usually put my caret at the end of the text, the solution above cause my caret to be missing. Is there any way for me to put an ellipses follow a caret?

[image]

[UPDATE 3]
Is there anyway to make the caret align at the very end?
[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you want to truncate the text and add ellipsis, you could add `overflow: hidden` to clip the text, and then use [`text-overflow: ellipsis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to add the '... ' ellipsis:

[**Updated Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/gFkLIlWjJADCHcdoZWC6?p=preview)

```
button.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zanko In my opinion, it's also good for usability because it indicates that something was truncated to the user.

Comment: Yes I really like this solution. Do you mind addressing my updated question? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible that the caret follow the ellipsis instead?

Comment: @Zanko Like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/cTBzHsx34IYPg9OXW5WP?p=preview), however you can't styling the ellipsis without styling the text, therefore you can't increase the space between '...' and the text.

Comment: Thank you so much that is exactly what I am looking for. Final question, Is there a way to make the caret align at the end? I have updated the picture! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really need to sit down and understand CSS one day:) This is very helpful!

Comment: Happy I saw this answer... Exact one that I was searching for.

Comment: This answer is correct, though it's worth mentioning that this works with specific values of `display`, like `display: block` and `display: inline-block`. So if this solution isn't working for you, try setting those values. Or see [@guysigner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34581567/7987987) below.

Answer (score 5):

**Just Use Following if you want to wrap the text inside the button**

```
white-space:normal !important;
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `width:auto;`. This happens because sometimes the text needs more than 50px. This can also be avoided by putting `overflow:hidden` which will make any text exceeding the button's width disappear, giving you a perfect 50px button.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, my intention is to hide the text rather than making the button the size of text.

Comment: If you read further into the post, I have mentioned that if you wish to hide the text instead, overflow:hidden will hide all text exceeding your buttons set width and height

Comment: Sorry I thought you were suggesting that I should use width:auto rather than overflow: hidden. Thank you for your response anyway! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
.truncate_text {
  max-width:90%;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

as a class to your button and feel free to play with the 90% width of the button (according to image above you would probable want it around 30%)

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

in the style tag. This will make it stay in the box and hide what's overflowing. 
Alternatively, choose a shorter title.